# Subscribed event is not firing

Tags: c#, wpf, events, mvvm, mvvm-light

I have a WPF User control and here is the code, where I initialize the view model and **subscribe** for the event.

```
   public partial class MyUserControl : UserControl
   {
    public MyUserControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = new MyUserControlViewModel();
        ((MyUserControlViewModel)this.DataContext).MainModel.MessageDataNew.CollectionChanged += NewMessage_CollectionChanged;

    }
```

This is the collection change event and it's not firing :(

```
   private void NewMessage_CollectionChanged(object sender, System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (MessageStatus != null)
        {
            var border = (Border)VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(MessageStatus, 0);
            var scrollViewer = (ScrollViewer)VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(border, 0);
            scrollViewer.ScrollToBottom();
        }
    }
```

This is my view model constructor. I am using `GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Messaging`

```
  public class MyUserControlViewModel: INotifyPropertyChanged
   {
     public MyUserControlViewModel()
     {        
        Messenger.Default.Register<string>(this, "SimulatorLogs", AddtoCollection);
     }

      public MainModel MainModel
      {
         get { return _mainModel; }
         set
         {   _mainModel = value;
             RaisePropertyChanged(() => MainModel);
         }
    }

    private void AddtoCollection(string measurementData)
    {
        MainModel.MessageDataNew.Add(measurementData);
    }
  }
```

Comment: Make sure you do not replace the view model instance, i.e. the DataContext value. E.g. by something like `<local:MyUserControl DataContext="{Binding …}"/>`. You should generally never explicitly assign the DataContext of a UserControl to some "own" view model. It should instead be passed by value inheritance of the DataContext property.